# Why is it that My Array is Undefined after Pushing an Element from an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

So basically, I have a web application that retrieves data from Firebase using rxjs observables.

here's my code,

```
initializeItems(){   
  this.travelList$ = this.plsdala.getTravelList()
  .snapshotChanges()
  .map(
    changes => {
      return changes.map(c=>({
        key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
      })).slice().reverse();//to reverse order
    })
    this.travelList$.subscribe(res => {
    for(let i=0;i<res.length;i++){
   this.ListOfitems.push (res[i].toAddress);
    }
  })
}
```

this is called from the constructor. problem here is that i cannot check if it is push successfully and if try to print in console , it wont print. why?
the element pushed is needed for filtering. heres is the code for filtter. but when i print the this.ListOfitems in console it is undefined and im wondering unto why? when the elements are initialized first

```
getItems(ev: any) {
   console.log("awdaw");
   console.log(this.ListOfitems);
   if (this.ListOfitems.length>1){
     console.log("otin");
     let val = ev.target.value;
     if (val && val.trim() != '') {
       this.ListOfitems = this.ListOfitems.filter((ListOfitems) => {
         return (ListOfitems.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
       })
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: you should provide the whole component code, in particular the definition of the array you are talking about.

Comment: and please properly indent the code as well as use camel case for naming variables, properties and classes, it is really hard to read right now.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide a live example, use stackblitz.com

Comment: hi i can provide the whole code but it wont work if put it online since it has alot of dependencies from ionic

Comment: plnkr.co/edit/y3opKdOAiky2YCf00beR?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

when you are declaring list of items if you want to push into the array you need to declare it empty first like this:

ListOfitems: string[] = [];